# Nginx - Decode URL query parameter and forward it as request header

Tags: nginx, basic-authentication, urlencode, url-encoding

I need to send some basic auth credentials (es. `user:pass`) to nginx in the form of query parameter (es. `http://example.com?BASIC_AUTH=dXNlcjpwYXNz`) and being able to forward them in the more usual `Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz` header form to a target server behind the proxy.

I'm already able to retrieve the value of the encoded auth string with a regular expression. The problem is that very often that value may contain some character that need to be percent-encoded in the URL. Es. `user:pass!` -> `?BASIC_AUTH=dXNlcjpwYXNzIQ==` becomes `?BASIC_AUTH=dXNlcjpwYXNzIQ%3D%3D`

Therefore, when I forward the request to the target server, I end up specifing `Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzIQ%3D%3D` which the target server will reject, giving a 401 Unauthorized.

How can I force nginx to decode the auth string before setting the Authorization header? Thanks in advance for your help.

Note: I can't send the auth string in the Authorization header in the first place due to some application-specific constraints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### "Pure" nginx solution

Unfortunately nginx does not provide a rich string operations set. I think there isn't a way to do global search-and-replace through some string (which can be a solution if we could replace all `%2B` with `+`, `%2F` with `/` and `%3D` with `=`). However there are circumstances under which nginx performs an urldecoding of some string - when this string becomes a part of an URI which will be forwarded to an upstream proxy server.

So we can add a value of a `BASIC_AUTH` request argument to the URI and make a proxy request to ourself:

```
# Main server block
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    ...

    location / {
        if ($arg_basic_auth) {
            # "basic_auth" request argument is present,
            # append "/decode_basic_auth/<BASE64_token>" to the URI
            # and go to the next location block
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /decode_basic_auth/$arg_basic_auth$1 last;
        }
        # No "basic_auth" request argument present,
        # can do a proxy call from here without setting authorization headers
        ...
    }

    location /decode_basic_auth/ {
        # This will be an internal location only
        internal;
        # Remove "basic_auth" request argument from the list of arguments
        if ($args ~* (.*)(^|&)basic_auth=[^&]*(\2|$)&?(.*)) {
            set $args $1$3$4;
        }
        # Some hostname for processing proxy subrequests
        proxy_set_header Host internal.basic.auth.localhost;
        # Do a subrequest to ourselfs, preserving other request arguments
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1$uri$is_args$args;
    }
}

# Additional server block for proxy subrequests processing
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name internal.basic.auth.localhost;

    # Got URI in form "/decode_basic_auth/<BASE64_token>/<Original_URI>"
    location ~ ^/decode_basic_auth/([^/]+)(/.*)$ {
        proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic $1";
        # Setup other HTTP headers here
        ...
        proxy_pass http://<upstream_server>$2$is_args$args;
    }

    # Do not serve other requests
    location / {
        return 444;
    }
}
```

Maybe this is not a very elegant solution, but it is tested and works.

### OpenResty / ngx_http_lua_module

This can be easily solved with [openresty](https://github.com/openresty/openresty) or [ngx_http_lua_module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) using [ngx.escape_uri](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxescape_uri) function:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    ...

    location / {
        set $auth $arg_basic_auth;
        if ($args ~* (.*)(^|&)basic_auth=[^&]*(\2|$)&?(.*)) {
            set $args $1$3$4;
        }
        rewrite_by_lua_block {
            ngx.var.auth = ngx.unescape_uri(ngx.var.auth)
        }
        proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic $auth";
        # Setup other HTTP headers here
        ...
        proxy_pass http://<upstream_server>;
    }
}
```